# Ошибка в MySQL синтаксисе

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте, коротко и ясно - трабл в записи в БД, вот код:
Несколько раз переписывал запрос и пр - ноль эмоций :С

Код нв oastebin: [Тык](http://pastebin.com/1g2uHCyL)

Comment: .

    INSERT into validate(`mail`, `key`) VALUES('$mail', '$key')

строка в одинарных кавычках воспринимается как строка, в обратных - как колонка

Comment: Спасибо, понял)эти кавычки сведут меня с ума

Comment: а чтобы не было проблем с кавычками и sql injection надо использовать mysqli или pdo с bind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$mail = 'mail';
$key = 'key';
print  "INSERT into validate('mail', 'key') VALUES('.$mail', '.$key')";
```

Вывод:

```
INSERT into validate('mail', 'key') VALUES('.mail', '.key')
```

Дальше разжёвывать?

И таки-да, забудьте уже наконец-то про такой `mysql_query()`.

Comment: Давай дальше разжевывать, ибо в мою тупую голову купидон говнокодинга так и не всунул свою отравленную стрелу.
Просто сухо - что не так. 
mysql_query() ок, переговнокодим.

Comment: тьфу
понял. спасибо.

Comment: А нет, вру, не понял

Comment: Точка зачем перед переменными $mail и $key